# Disable Ubuntu Update Manager's new version warning

Tags: upgrade

How to disallow Ubuntu to upgrade from like 11.10 to 12.04?

I know that its your wish if you want to upgrade, but I don't want the message in update manager that says a new release is available to get displayed.

All help will be appreciated

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Open the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` with your favorite text editor, ie:

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

[image]

Change the *Prompt=* line from `Prompt=foo_setting` to `Prompt=never`.

If you want a graphical way of doing it open the Ubuntu Software Center and under *Edit* > *Software Sources* > *Updates* you will find a `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version` option, from the drop box select *Never*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you also tell me how'd you change the terminal background? Pretty cool I must say! :)

Comment: @user51447 _Edit_ > _Profile Preferences_ > _Colors_ and _Edit_ > _Profile Preferences_ > _Background_ will allow you to config what you need in `gnome-terminal`. If the answer works please use the check green mark next to the up and down vote to mark is answered.

Comment: If motd has already started mentioning an update available on login, do:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
then
sudo update-motd
to force it to update to this change.

Answer (score 15):

Or just use sed! We just added this to our setup script to avoid our users from borking their own systems by doing upgrades.

```
sudo sed -i 's/Prompt=.*/Prompt=never/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Comment: How could upgrade bork the system?

Answer (score 4):

To stop Ubuntu nagging you:

```
nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Change `Prompt=normal` to `Prompt=never`:

To exit `nano` press the combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and then answer to the question of saving changes with <kbd>Y</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

You can also just disable checking altogether by doing:

```
apt-get remove ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
```

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of Ubuntu, using the GUI, you should see an option

**Notify me of a new Ubuntu version**, therein select **Never**

[image]