# How to stop updates nagging me in 11.10

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, unity, launcher, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable Ubuntu Update Manager’s new version warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115913/disable-ubuntu-update-managers-new-version-warning)

I'm running on 11.10. My computer keeps on bugging me about 12.04, but I don't want it to. Please help as it is annoying me and my unity launcher is blocking some of the screen, as the update icon is wobbling.

Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the option of your preference in the "Software Sources" settings application.

[image]

Please be aware that you'll have to move to a more recent version in less than half a year, as 11.10 will receive its End-of-Life status.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll upgrade straight away when it prompts me to.

Comment: @nerof61 It won't bother prompting you to update if you set it to "Never". You'll have to take that initiative yourself.

Comment: Ok. Got you. I think it expires 2013/04.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Update Manager and click Settings. Change "Notify me of a New Ubuntu version:" to "Never".